Aggregating clocktables from table, rather than heading, data
I have an archive of org-mode files each containing a clocktable with clock activity for a particular day.  These files contain only the tables, without the associated org headings and clock logs from which they were generated. Is there a reasonably simple way to produce a master clock report for all the days in my archive?
I see two main approaches. One is to try to leverage the clocktable functionality and somehow make it work with tabular data rather than the clock logs under the relevant headings. (My understanding is that clocktable does not natively support this.) The other is to consider the clocktables as just ordinary tables and find a way to merge them. The latter approach is challenging because one would want (1) to have a single row for entries that occur multiple times (with a clock value that reflects their summation) and (2) entries under a given heading to be grouped together even if they are in different tables. E.g. from these two tables
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 9 :narrow 500 :fileskip0 t :block "2024-04-17" 
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2024-04-18 Thu 18:14], for Wednesday, April 17, 2024.
| File     | Headline                                         | Time |      |
|----------+--------------------------------------------------+------+------|
|          | ALL *Total time*                                 | 5:45 |      |
|----------+--------------------------------------------------+------+------|
| work.org | *File time*                                      | 5:45 |      |
|          | Heading1                                         | 5:13 |      |
|          | \_  Script para aplicar mp3 chapters en mp3      |      | 2:53 |
|          | \_  Theme dark / light no se aplica inicialmente |      | 1:12 |
|          | \_  Regresión comportamiento index               |      | 0:19 |
|          | \_  Reunión Prot                                 |      | 0:49 |
|          | Heading2                                         | 0:32 |      |
|          | \_  update Funciones clock tlon-babel            |      | 0:32 |
 #+END:

#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 9 :narrow 500 :fileskip0 t :block "2024-04-18" 
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2024-04-18 Thu 23:32], for Thursday, April 18, 2024.
| File     | Headline                              | Time |      |
|----------+---------------------------------------+------+------|
|          | ALL *Total time*                      | 3:09 |      |
|----------+---------------------------------------+------+------|
| work.org | *File time*                           | 3:09 |      |
|          | Heading1                              | 3:01 |      |
|          | \_  Bug report management             |      | 0:55 |
|          | \_  [bisagra-front]                   |      | 1:07 |
|          | \_  Player: opción alwaysExpanded     |      | 0:16 |
|          | \_  Regresión comportamiento index    |      | 0:43 |
|          | Heading2                              | 0:08 |      |
|          | \_  update Funciones clock tlon-babel |      | 0:08 |
#+END:

we want to produce something like
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2024-04-18 Thu 18:14], for Wednesday, April 17, 2024.
| File     | Headline                                         | Time |      |
|----------+--------------------------------------------------+------+------|
|          | ALL *Total time*                                 | 8:54 |      |
|----------+--------------------------------------------------+------+------|
| work.org | *File time*                                      | 8:54 |      |
|          | Heading1                                         | 8:14 |      |
|          | \_  Script para aplicar mp3 chapters en mp3      |      | 2:53 |
|          | \_  Theme dark / light no se aplica inicialmente |      | 1:12 |
|          | \_  Regresión comportamiento index               |      | 1:02 |
|          | \_  Reunión Prot                                 |      | 0:49 |
|          | \_  Bug report management                        |      | 0:55 |
|          | \_  [bisagra-front]                              |      | 1:07 |
|          | \_  Player: opción alwaysExpanded                |      | 0:16 |
|          | Heading2                                         | 0:40 |      |
|          | \_  update Funciones clock tlon-babel            |      | 0:40 |
#+END:

